# Instant messaging with threads

Tags: windows, linux, chat

When talking with a friend over Jabber, it's sometimes hard to understand to which message was he responding to. Other times, we're even having multiple conversations at the same time, which is even more confusing.

Email solved this a long time ago by using threads, so you can clearly see to which message another message is responding to. So I'm looking for an Instant messaging client that can do something like this too.

It should work on both Windows and Linux.